# Expression Sketchflow : Is it possible to run full screen? (and without window border?)

Tags: expression-blend, sketchflow

I did some sketchflow prototypes for a client.

The client need the application to be "touchable" on a 19" display, so I would like to try to launch the prototypes in full screen on the display (as will the final application be).

I searched through the net and found a "solution" : transform my sketchflow project in a Blend Project, and then tell the blend project to run in full screen mode.

This solution doesn't work all the time as the tutorials say, and doesn't work for me apparently :-(

Do you know any other solution?

Thanks for your help,

Antoine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably the best solution, what part of it didn't work? If you want to send me your solution I can help convert it so it will run without the SketchFlow player.

First.Last@microsoft.com using my name.